# Generating import library from dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker

So, I downloaded this FFT library (called FFTW, [here](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3)) for Visual C++, but, unfortunately for me, the libraries that were included were in .dll format. There were instructions on importing the library on windows using the lib.exe program, [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html), but when I run lib.exe using the parameters it set out, it gives me "Fatal Error Lnk1104: cannot open  libfftw3-3.def". I tried running the command as an administrator thinking that maybe my permissions were preventing from opening the file, but that didn't seem to work either. I'm not familiar with this process at all, so I'm sort of at a loss. Thanks in advance, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with the absolute path of libfftw3-3.def

Comment: No, in retrospect it seems kind of stupid, but I hadn't. It seems to work now though, so forgive my ignorance and thanks for the fix